# How to get errors like undefined variable from Monaco Editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I would like to get errors from Monaco.

For exemple in the playground ( https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-editor-hello-world ) if I write `alert(test)` I will have the following message: `ReferenceError: test is not defined`.
When I do this on my project it doesn't print the errors

Answer (score 0):

When you see the message `ReferenceError: test is not defined` this is not directly from the Monaco Editor but the implementation of the Playground page. Which is when you press **run** to try your code snippet out.

Its a friendly way to let you know something went wrong and printing the error on the page for you to see, as opposed to logging the error message in the console of developer tools of the browser you are using.

I hope this helps answer your question